# Python dictionaries, key existence with fallback

Tags: python

Is there any difference, gotcha or disadvantage between these approaches?

```
foo = dict(key=u"")
bar = foo.get('key', 'foobar')
```

vs

```
foo = dict(key=u"")
bar = bool(foo['key']) or 'foobar'
```

Comment: The second one raises an error? It doesn't actually fallback

Comment: The first one is correct, and the second one is not?

Comment: No it certainly does not

Comment: `>>> foo = dict(key=u"")
>>> bool(foo['ky']) or 'foobar'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#22>", line 1, in <module>
    bool(foo['ky']) or 'foobar'
KeyError: 'ky'`

Comment: Execute the code, have a look at `bar` in each case and you will see the difference. In the first case `bar` is an empty string, in the second case `bar` is `'foobar'`.

Comment: I did you misspelled key it works fine here

Comment: `foo.get(key, 'foobar')` is `u''`, while `bool(foo['key'])` returns True or False, depending on the nature of the stored value. Apart from the KeyError if `key` is *not* present, that's a huge difference in your result.

Comment: @MartijnPieters thanks, that IS a huge difference but I was wondering if there was any other difference when a key is always present, for instance in evaluation and sorts.

Comment: @Martijn: `bool(foo['key'])` returns `False` actually (in this case).

Comment: @Hedde: Didn't you read my comment? In your examples, `bar` already gets two different values assigned. Isn't this enough to proof that the second way is not an acceptable?

Comment: @FelixKling: yeah, part of the problem, of course.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should most definitely not use the second form, because it will throw a `KeyError` if the key does not exist your dictionary.  You're only getting acceptable behavior out of the second form because the key was set.

Comment: *and* the OP is getting a boolean instead of the value of `foo['key']`..

Answer (score 6):

The first piece of code tries to get a value from `foo` associated with `key`, and if `foo` does not have the key `key`, defaults to `foobar`. So there are two cases here:

1. `foo` has the key `key`, so `bar` is set to `foo[key]`
2. `foo` does not have the key `key`, so `bar` is set to `"foobar"`

The second looks at the value associated with the key `key` in `foo`, and if that value is falsy (that is, if `bool(foo[key])==False`), it defaults to `foobar`. If `foo` does not have the key `key` it raises a `KeyError`. So there are *three* cases here:

1. `foo` has the key `key`, and `bool(foo[key])==True`, so `bar` is set to `True`
2. `foo` has the key `key`, and `bool(foo[key])==False`, so `bar` is set to `"foobar"`
3. `foo` does not have the key `key`, so the code raises a `KeyError`

Answer (score 4):

The 2nd example will raise `KeyError` if `foo['key']` doesn't exist.

If you want to assign a default value to `bar` if `foo['key']` doesn't exist or contains falsey value, this would be the Pythonic way to do it:

```
bar = foo.get('key') or 'foobar'
```

Comment: I wouldn't use `or`. Think about the case where `foo = dict(key=None)` for example.

Comment: I get your point, my example is valid only if non-existent `foo['key']` and `None`/other falsey value means the same thing to user.

Comment: 8 years later, it would still be worth updating the answer to say that in the answer itself. If you want a fallback value, you can't use `or` (you have to use `get`) because `or` will _overwrite_ the real value if that value is falsey. It's not a fallback, it's a logical assignment.

Answer (score 3):

Yes:

`foo.get('key', 'foobar')` always returns something (if there is a key names 'key' it will return its value, and if there is no such key it will return 'foobar').

but `bool(foo['key']) or 'foobar'` can raise a `KeyError` if there is no such key named 'key'.

Furthermore - the use of `or` here is not indicative, so the `get` method is preferable.

Answer (score 1):

This is the problem with using `bool()`

```
one = {"my_key": None}

print "Get:", one.get("my_key")
print "Bool:", bool(one.get("my_key"))
print "Get with falback:", one.get("my_key", "other")

Get: None
Bool: False
Get with falback: None
```

Note that there is a value in there, `None`, but bool evaluates to false. You should use `get("key", "default")`, it's designed to do the job.

Comment: The OP's example already exposes that behaviour, an empty string is falsy.

Comment: Indeed, and my answer shows that they are different. Unless I misread it?

Comment: No, I just wanted to point out that the problem already occurs in the OP's example, that's all.

Answer (score 1):

If you think `foo = dict(key=u"")` will produce a dictionary wich default value is an empty string, you are mistaken. You'll need a `defaultdict` for that:

```
In [6]: bool(foo['key']) or 'foobar'
Out[6]: 'foobar'
In [7]: foo = dict(key='')
In [9]: bool(foo['nokey']) or 'foobar'
KeyError: 'nokey'
```

Either use `defaultdict`, or `dict.get`, or even `dict.setdefault`.

The good all way works too:

```
In [10]: try:
   ....:     v = foo['nokey']
   ....: except KeyError:
   ....:     v = 'foobar'
   ....:     

In [11]: v
Out[11]: 'foobar'
```